# Any way to edit for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

**Set Up:**

I have two select elements and a button.

The first select element (id="mySelect") is filled with 3 options added through HTML. The other (id="lvlDropMenu") has 20 options, and was filled using a for loop so that I don't have to manually add or remove  new options if I want to change the length of the LvlDropMenu, which I plan to.

**What I want to do:**

*Using pure javascript* when I click the "start button" I want to modify the options displayed in LvlDropmenu based on the data-tier of the selected "mySelect".

**For instance:**

When I select Object 1 (it's data-tier = T1) and hit the start button, I want the "lvlDropDown"  to only display options 5-15.

**Problem:**

Ideally, I would like to use a method similar to slice() to extract and display options, but as far as I know that only works with strings.

**Considering this, would it be more efficient to:**

- create an array with N number of values
- make a for loop to loop through the array and add new options with each value/innerHTML equal to N++ (option 1, option 2, etc, etc)
- make an if statement to slice()/modify the array based on the data-tier of selected object so that for loop in turn is modified?

Any tips or viable solutions would be greatly appreciated, cause I've been stomped for days.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 20;i++)
selectLvl.add(new Option(i));

var startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
startBtn.addEventListener("click", start);

function start(){
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

var selectedObjectTier = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-tier");

if(selectedObjectTier == "T1")
{mySelect.length = 1}
//to make sure button/conditions work
//what I actually want is for the LvlDropMenu to display options 5-15
else{alert("Other")};;



};
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" size="4">
  <option value="Object 1" data-tier="T1">Object 1</option>
  <option value="Object 2" data-tier="T2">Object 2</option>
  <option value="Object 3" data-tier="T3">Object 3</option>
</select>


<form id="lvlDropMenu">
  <select name="selectLvl" id="selectLvl">
        <option>Choose your Level:</option>
    </select>
</form>

<button type="button" id="startBtn" class="menu" >Start</button>
```

Comment: Ther is also a `slice` method for arrays in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert into the `<form>` a new `<select>` with specific options 
every time the button is clicked.

Set predefined start and end for `data-tier`

```
var dataTiers = {
  T1: [5, 15],
  T2: [3, 13],
  T3: [1, 10]
}
```

**In total**

```js
var button = document.getElementById("startBtn");
var dataTiers = {
  T1: [5, 15],
  T2: [3, 13],
  T3: [1, 10]
}

function insertSelectIntoForm(formId, selectId, arr) { // id === name, arr -> [start, end]
  var form = document.getElementById(formId),
    select = document.createElement("select"),
    choose = new Option(),
    text = document.createTextNode("Choose your Level: ");

  form.innerHTML = ""; // Clear form

  select.setAttribute("name", selectId);
  select.setAttribute("id", selectId);
  choose.appendChild(text);
  select.appendChild(choose);

  for (var i = arr[0]; i < (arr[1] + 1); i += 1) { // arr[0] === start, arr[1] === end
    var option = new Option(i);
    option.setAttribute("value", i); // Set value
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
  form.appendChild(select);
}

function start() {
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect"),
    dataTier = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-tier");
  insertSelectIntoForm("lvlDropMenu", "selectLvl", dataTiers[dataTier]);
}

insertSelectIntoForm("lvlDropMenu", "selectLvl", [1, 20]);
button.addEventListener("click", start);
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" size="4">
  <option value="Object 1" data-tier="T1">Object 1</option>
  <option value="Object 2" data-tier="T2">Object 2</option>
  <option value="Object 3" data-tier="T3">Object 3</option>
</select>

<!-- Empty form, select will be created with JavaScript -->
<form id="lvlDropMenu"></form>

<button type="button" id="startBtn" class="menu">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.slice(begin, end)` to select the part of the options you would like to use.

Pass these options into a function which populates `#LvlDropMenu`, e.g. `populateMenu(optionArray)`.

Here is an example:

Use `Array.slice(begin, end)`
to select the part of the options you would like to use.

Pass these options into a
function which populates `#LvlDropMenu`, e.g.
`populateMenu(optionArray)`.

Here is an example:

```
var allOptions = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    selectLvl.add(new Option(i));
    allOptions.push(new Option(i));
}

var startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
var menu = document.getElementById("lvlDropMenu ");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", start);

function start() {
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

    var selectedObjectTier = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-tier");
    mySelect.length = 1;

    // check which tier is selected
    switch (selectedObjectTier) {
        // each case call `populateMenu()` with a subset of options
        case "T1":
            populateMenu(allOptions.slice(0, 5));
            break;

        case "T2":
            populateMenu(allOptions.slice(5, 10));
            break;

        case "T3":
            populateMenu(allOptions.slice(10, 19));
            break;

        default:
            alert("Other");
            break;
    }

};

function populateMenu(options) {
    // clear menu
    menu.innerHTML = "";

    // add the options, by looping through the array
    options.forEach(function(option) {
        var el = document.createElement("OPTION");
        el.value = option;
        el.innerHTML = option;
        menu.appendChild(el);
    });
}
```

Comment: First off,thank you for your help! 
After fixing some minor mistakes(
1. there's a missing ")" after populateMenu(allOptions.slice(10, 19)
2. there's a misplaced "}" after case 3)
I've run into an issue: 
When I try to run your solution in my editor, "I get the error: _allOptions is not defined_
I understand the purpose of allOptions in the context of the code, but nothing else (as in if it's proper syntax, or implemented in the right way). Could you explain?

Comment: Thank you for noting the minor mistakes, I have fixed them. Secondly, `allOption` serves as a variable to store all the options. Create your own variable, which has the options for `T1`, `T2` and `T3` combined.